# Application auto build versioning

Tags: go

Is it possible to increment a minor version number automatically each time a Go app is compiled?

I would like to set a version number inside my program, with an autoincrementing section:

```
$ myapp -version
MyApp version 0.5.132
```

Being 0.5 the version number I set, and 132 a value that increments automatically each time the binary is compiled.

Is this possible in Go?

Answer (score 381, accepted):

The Go linker ([go tool link](http://golang.org/cmd/link/)) has an option to set the value of an uninitialised string variable:

> ```
> -X importpath.name=value
>   Set the value of the string variable in importpath named name to
> ```

value.
        Note that before Go 1.5 this option took two separate arguments.
        Now it takes one argument split on the first = sign.

As part of your build process, you could set a version string variable using this. You can pass this through the `go` tool using `-ldflags`. For example, given the following source file:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var xyz string

func main() {
    fmt.Println(xyz)
}
```

Then:

```
$ go run -ldflags "-X main.xyz=abc" main.go
abc
```

In order to set `main.minversion` to the build date and time when building:

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.minversion=`date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`" service.go
```

If you compile without initializing `main.minversion` in this way, it will contain the empty string.

Comment: Will that value be saved into the binary if I use `go bouild` instead of `go run`?

Comment: `go build -ldflags "-X main.minversion \`date -u +.%Y%m%d%.H%M%S\`" service.go`

Comment: This does not seem to work for me in Go 1.1.1:

`$ go run -ldflags "-X main.xyz abc" main.go` -> `go run: no go files listed`

Comment: @felixge I just tried it again with Go 1.1.1, and it worked for me. Anyway, "go run" is just for playing; use "go build" as in Sebastián's comment.

Comment: If you're on Windows, here's one you can use from the command prompt: `go build -ldflags "-X main.minversion \"%date%\""`. This doesn't work on LiteIDE though.

Comment: goxc does this for you :) by default it compiles with -ldflags "-Xmain.VERSION x.x.x -Xmain.BUILD_DATE CurrentDateInISO8601", but you can configure those variable names if you like. See https://github.com/laher/goxc ... (disclaimer: I wrote goxc)

Comment: Note: -ldflags -X will work for variables in the main package but not for packages. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/F6uxUrKZAsE/StdNt-CX3k4J

Comment: date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S

Comment: I believe that the last sentence is not correct: a string cannot be nil in Go (when declared it just assumes the value of an empty string). Therefore `go build service.go` would work as well.

Comment: working example with new 1.5 syntax for adding the buildtime variable ```go build -ldflags "-X 'main.buildtime=$(date -u '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')'"```

Comment: The xyz variable must be exported, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: @MaartenO. I just copy-pasted the example and it works fine with go 1.5.

Comment: notice that full package name is required.

`go build -ldflags "-X pkg.version=123"` won't work

while 

`go build -ldflags "-X path/to/pkg.version=123"` work as expected.

hope it helps.

Comment: Does this somehow work for a library. Let's say i want to use the library in another main. How can i make this ldflags valid while building the library?

Comment: @Strubbl -ldflags only applies when you create the final binary. You would have to supply that each time you create a binary using the library.

Comment: It's convenient to overwrite globals initialized with a message like: the build did not provide this value.

Comment: @Strubbl yes this also works for a library. if the library is in your /vendor/ folder the path/to/pkg  will be really long. 

e.g. I have a library that I call instrulog that is included in my background worker rc-nag-notification-scheduler-worker 

go build -ldflags "-X bitbucket.org/newyuinc/rc-nag-notification-scheduler-worker/vendor/bitbucket.org/newyuinc/instrulog.Version=bd48434-dev"

Comment: in  "-X main.xyz=abc"  main is the package name or file_name or method name?

Comment: @PankajSingh as mentioned in the -help output, it's the [package import path](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#ImportPaths).

Comment: is it possible to initialize a struct's field (of type string) with this method? I want to logically group a few build values - and trying to set them with say "-X main.BuildInfo.GitHash=123abc7 -X main.BuildInfo.Unixtime=1541987669"  has no effect on the struct i.e. the struct string fields have their _zero_ values.

Comment: @colminator not directly, you would instead have to initialise the struct variable from package-level string vars.

Comment: "The string variable must exist, it must be a variable, not a constant, and its value must not be initialized by a function call" https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GcToolchainTricks

Comment: I beleive you can actually initialize already initialized variables, too

Comment: with Go 1.13+ modules, you need to specify the entire git module URL

Comment: what if  I use "replace" in go.mod. the `importpath` should be the original module or replaced one?

Answer (score 43):

## Use `ldflags` to set variables in `main` package:

With file `main.go`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var (
    version string
    build   string
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("version=", version)
    fmt.Println("build=", build)
}
```

Then run:

```
go run \
  -ldflags "-X main.version=1.0.0 -X main.build=12082019" \ 
  main.go
```

Build:

```
go build -o mybinary \
  -ldflags "-X main.version=1.0.0 -X 'main.build=$(date)'" \ 
  main.go
```

---

## Use `ldflags` to set variable in a `non-main` package:

With file `config.go`:

```
package config

import "fmt"

var (
    Version string
)

func LogVersion() {
    fmt.Println("version=", Version)
}
```

You will also need file `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/user/repo/config"
}

func main() {
    config.LogVersion()
}
```

Build your binary first:

```
go build -o mybinary main.go
```

Find the full path of variable name you want to set:

```
go tool nm <path_to_binary> | grep Version
```

Run and build the binary again but with the `ldflags`:

```
go run \
  -ldflags "-X github.com/user/repo/config.Version=1.0.0" \
  main.go --version       


go build -o mybinary \
  -ldflags "-X github.com/user/repo/config.Version=1.0.0" \
  main.go
```

---

Inspired by https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GcToolchainTricks#including-build-information-in-the-executable

---

Also if you are using `goreleaser` then read this https://goreleaser.com/cookbooks/using-main.version/?h=ldflag#using-the-mainversion-ldflag :

> Default wise GoReleaser sets three ldflags:
>
> main.version: Current Git tag
> main.commit: Current git commit SHA
> main.date: Date according RFC3339

---

If you want to see this in action: https://github.com/hoto/fuzzy-repo-finder/blob/master/pkg/config/config.go

Comment: The link to the goreleaser documentation changed: https://goreleaser.com/environment/#using-the-mainversion

Comment: Changed again: https://goreleaser.com/cookbooks/using-main.version/

Answer (score 34):

Additionally I would like to post a small example how to use git and a makefile:

```
--- Makefile ----

# This how we want to name the binary output
BINARY=gomake

# These are the values we want to pass for VERSION and BUILD
# git tag 1.0.1
# git commit -am "One more change after the tags"
VERSION=`git describe --tags`
BUILD=`date +%FT%T%z`

# Setup the -ldflags option for go build here, interpolate the variable values
LDFLAGS_f1=-ldflags "-w -s -X main.Version=${VERSION} -X main.Build=${BUILD} -X main.Entry=f1"
LDFLAGS_f2=-ldflags "-w -s -X main.Version=${VERSION} -X main.Build=${BUILD} -X main.Entry=f2"

# Builds the project
build:
    go build ${LDFLAGS_f1} -o ${BINARY}_f1
    go build ${LDFLAGS_f2} -o ${BINARY}_f2

# Installs our project: copies binaries
install:
    go install ${LDFLAGS_f1}

# Cleans our project: deletes binaries
clean:
    if [ -f ${BINARY} ] ; then rm ${BINARY} ; fi

.PHONY: clean install
```

The make file will create two executables. One is executing function one, the other will take function two as main entry:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

var (

        Version string
        Build   string
        Entry   string

        funcs = map[string]func() {
                "f1":functionOne,"f2":functionTwo,
        }

)

func functionOne() {
    fmt.Println("This is function one")
}

func functionTwo() {
    fmt.Println("This is function two")
}

func main() {

        fmt.Println("Version: ", Version)
        fmt.Println("Build Time: ", Build)

    funcs[Entry]()

}
```

Then just run:

```
make
```

You will get:

```
mab@h2470988:~/projects/go/gomake/3/gomake$ ls -al
total 2020
drwxrwxr-x 3 mab mab    4096 Sep  7 22:41 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 mab mab    4096 Aug 16 10:00 ..
drwxrwxr-x 8 mab mab    4096 Aug 17 16:40 .git
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mab mab 1023488 Sep  7 22:41 gomake_f1
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mab mab 1023488 Sep  7 22:41 gomake_f2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mab mab     399 Aug 16 10:21 main.go
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mab mab     810 Sep  7 22:41 Makefile
mab@h2470988:~/projects/go/gomake/3/gomake$ ./gomake_f1
Version:  1.0.1-1-gfb51187
Build Time:  2016-09-07T22:41:38+0200
This is function one
mab@h2470988:~/projects/go/gomake/3/gomake$ ./gomake_f2
Version:  1.0.1-1-gfb51187
Build Time:  2016-09-07T22:41:39+0200
This is function two
```

Comment: Or simpler: just make two main in two different directories. This solution seems to be seriously overengineered.

Answer (score 28):

I had trouble using the `-ldflags` parameter when building my mixed command-line app and library project, so I ended up using a Makefile target to generate a Go source file containing my app's version and the build date:

```
BUILD_DATE := `date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M`
VERSIONFILE := cmd/myapp/version.go

gensrc:
    rm -f $(VERSIONFILE)
    @echo "package main" > $(VERSIONFILE)
    @echo "const (" >> $(VERSIONFILE)
    @echo "  VERSION = \"1.0\"" >> $(VERSIONFILE)
    @echo "  BUILD_DATE = \"$(BUILD_DATE)\"" >> $(VERSIONFILE)
    @echo ")" >> $(VERSIONFILE)
```

In my `init()` method, I do this:

```
flag.Usage = func() {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s version %s\n", os.Args[0], VERSION)
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "built %s\n", BUILD_DATE)
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "usage:")
    flag.PrintDefaults()
}
```

If you wanted an atomically-increasing build number instead of a build date, however, you would probably need to create a local file that contained the last build number.  Your Makefile would read the file contents into a variable, increment it, insert it in the `version.go` file instead of the date, and write the new build number back to the file.

Comment: Nice solution. Still, I think I've found the reason for the -ldflags troubles. If the file containing variable being updated by -X isn't touched, then the compilation doesn't trigger and you have old version in the binary. My solution was to touch a small file containing only variable being reset via -ldflags "-X ..."

Answer (score 13):

On Windows OS given the program below

```
package main

import "fmt"

var (
    version string
    date    string
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("version=%s, date=%s", version, date)
}
```

You can build using

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.version=0.0.1 -X main.date=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%T%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%"
```

Date format assumes your environment `echo %date%` is `Fri 07/22/2016` and `echo %time%` is `16:21:52.88`

Then the output will be: `version=0.0.1, date=2016-07-22T16:21:52`

Answer (score 11):

to use multi `-ldflags`:

```
$ go build -ldflags "-X name1=value1 -X name2=value2" -o path/to/output
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the other answers, with recent go versions it's also possible to write a buildid to an ELF section - though that's not so easily readable from within the program.

I write the same value to both, using something like the following:

```
BuildInfo:= "BUILD #x, branch @ rev built yymmdd hh:mm:ss"
// note the nested quotes "''" required to get a string with 
// spaces passed correctly to the underlying tool
ldFl := fmt.Sprintf("-X 'main.buildId=%s' -s -w '-buildid=%s'", BuildInfo, BuildInfo)
args := []string{
    "build",
    "-ldflags", ldFl,
    "-trimpath",
    "-gcflags", "-dwarf=false",
}
buildpath:="path/to/my/cmd"
args=append(args,buildpath)
buildCmd:=exec.Command("go", args...)
```

I use this with `mage`, a build tool written in go. You don't need the extra flags above, but I chose those to strip as much information as possible from release binaries.

(off topic: Mage requires a bit more upfront work than something like Make, but is much easier to extend/maintain than a make-based build system - plus you don't have to switch mental gears between go and some other syntax.)