# Golang: How to get data files from package directory

Tags: go

Is there a standard way to READ files within the package directory?

Just as an example, I have a file "VERSION" that contains the semantic version of my package, how can I read that file within my go application once the application has been installed?

I've tried all the suggestions on this SO: [Golang: How to Get the Directory of the Currently running File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537257/golang-how-to-get-the-directory-of-the-currently-running-file)

A third-party package "osext" was the only method that actually produced reliable results.

EDIT: For my specific example, `go build -ldflags "-X main.VERSION X.X.X"` works perfectly.

Comment: After you install your package, there's no guarantee where the binary is in relation to the original source, or that the source will still be there at all.

Comment: So how could I package the file into the binary?  Or is that a terrible idea?

Comment: Packing files into the binary: [What's the best way to bundle static resources in a Go program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904441/whats-the-best-way-to-bundle-static-resources-in-a-go-program)

Comment: Put the version string in the source directly, or add it at build time with `go build -ldflags "-X main.SemVer $(cat VERSION)" my/package/` : (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354518/golang-application-auto-build-versioning)

Comment: @JimB It's worth reminding that the [recommended syntax in Go 1.5+](http://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.5#link) is `-X pkg.Var=value`.

Comment: @Ainar-G: yes. I didn't mention it yet, because unfortunately that syntax *doesn't* work on the current release, while the old syntax will continue to work with a warning message ;)

Comment: In my projects, I actually use git annotated tags.  Whenever I want to update my package, I call `git tag -a 0.5` then in my Makefile I do `go build -ldflags "-x main.Version=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`" it works okay for me.  The only issues, is that if your package is go get'ed you the Version will be a blank string.