# In a Golang application, how to embed a version in a other package than main?

Tags: go, version, auto-versioning

Inspired by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354518/golang-application-auto-build-versioning) I wanted to use the same mechanism to embed a version number in my golang application. However I'm using the [Cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra) command line parser and want to have a `version` sub-command. This leads to the following directory and package structure:

```
.
|-- cmd                                                                   
`-- version.go                                                    
|-- main.go
```

Up to now I have tried the following:

```
go run -ldflags "-X cmd/version.versionString=0.1.0" main.go version
```

-

```
go run -ldflags "-X version.versionString=0.1.0" main.go version
```

-

```
go run -ldflags "-X version.VersionString=0.1.0" main.go version
```

With `version.go` containing a variable declaration like:

```
var versionString string
```

and

```
var VersionString string
```

respectively.

I've also tried to put the variable declarations in `main.go` but then I'm  not clear how to reference the variables in `version.go` for this option I tried:

```
import "github.com/basbossink/psiw"
....
fmt.Println(psiw.VersionString)
```

-

```
import "github.com/basbossink/psiw/main"
...
fmt.Println(main.VersionString)
```

In both cases the compiler complains that `psiw` and `main` respectively are unknown.
Note that using the `VersionString` in `main` gives the expected result.

I would prefer a solution where the link flags point to the variable in the `version` package since they don't require a *back-pointer*. But any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the [Hugo source](https://github.com/spf13/hugo) I've discovered the answer to my question. The trick is to use:

```
go run -ldflags "-X github.com/basbossink/psiw/cmd.versionString=0.1.0" main.go version
```

So I made two mistakes:

- I mixed up the notion of package and source file, the `version.go` file had `package cmd` as it's package statement.
- The way to reference the variable is to use the fully qualified name.